# Spring Security Producing Null CSRF Token - Property or field 'parameterName' cannot be found on null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spelevaluationexception

I have been trying to implement Spring Security for a few days and have been struggling with the `csrf tokens`.

I've debugged down into `CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor` and found that the following line is returning null.

```
CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
```

Using Thymeleaf I have the following form:

```
<form th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" method="post">
  <label for="j_username">Username</label>:
  <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" /> <br />
  <label for="j_password">Password</label>:
  <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" /> <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
  <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

It doesn't render and throws the following exception:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "_csrf.parameterName" (loginsample:19)] with root cause org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'parameterName' cannot be found on null

Why this might be?

Comment: are you using spring-security 4?

Comment: How do you generate csrf token?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Java or XML config? If XML, make sure you enable the csrf token:

`<http> ...
<csrf />
</http>`

You might also need to import the JSP taglib:
Import the security tags:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

then add this in the head as well:

```
<sec:csrfMetaTags />
```

You might need to import the taglib dependency.